# How can I generate some public and private keys on both sides with low overhead?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, key-management, key-generation, key-exchange, asymmetric

We have an Authority Center (CA) generating some public and private keys for each client (more than one pair for each client). One method for sending keys to client is sharing a secret key between CA and client, and then sending key pairs and certificates by symmetric encryption method (with secret key). But overhead will be high, so i need an efficient method with low message overhead and time for key pairs transmission. How can i do it?
is there any way to both sides share a secret key and then generates key pairs using it, without transmitting key pairs, (a way that confirm the key pairs are reliable for CA)?

a way is that public keys are hashed to a common value. is it possible for clients to generates such public keys? but i think it takes a lot of time.

it's very important for me, please help me.

Comment: Why is your CA generating the clients' key pairs?

Comment: Each key pair should be used one period and server not always available.

Comment: What prevents you from using the default method of having the clients generate a key pair and send the public key to the CA in an authenticated manner?  (presumably authenticated by a secret key)

Comment: Is it that the client can't afford to resend it the necessary number of times?

Comment: I edited my question, key pairs should be reliable for other clients (CA should confirm them).

Comment: For using key pairs in message exchanging, Other clients don't know who is the sender but they know sender is verified by CA. I need more than one key.

Comment: Is "other clients don't know who is the sender" a feature or merely a consequence of your approach?

Comment: it's a necessary feature in the network.

Comment: Do you care whether or not a client can detect that the sender used the client's own key?

Comment: maybe a comment help you to understand problem. these are important for message exchanging in this network: 1. messages data are not private and so no needing to encryption, 2. the ownership of the message should be verified by other clients (by a certificate or similar document from CA in the message to verify public key used for signing is from an insider client confirmed by CA), and 3. each key pair must be used for a short period.

Comment: that comment doesn't address my previous comment

Comment: it is important for client that the message is send by a legitimate sender, it doesn't know who owns the keys?

Comment: Now, it sounds like the network could use a [group signature scheme](https://www.google.com/#q=group+signature+scheme).

Comment: group signature is a good scheme, but verification and revocation costs are high.. although i think this model is the only solution until now.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to both sides share a secret key and then generates key pairs using it

You can derive further keys from an initial shared key, there are various key derivation mechanisms that would allow you to do this, but you still have the problem of distributing the initial key. Anyone who intercepts this key could replicate the derivation process and derive the same subsequent keys, so you still need to securely transfer this initial key and you have the same problem you started with. This applies to your suggested solution as well; wrapping the keys with a shared secret is a sound idea but you still need a way of securely sharing that secret.

Key distribution is probably the single most difficult part of implementing a cryptographic system. Distributing symmetric/secret keys, as would be needed in the solution you mention, is especially difficult, which is why they are often negotiated wrapped under asymmetric keys, such as is the case for SSL and similar, as the encryption is done using the public half of the receivers key which is not confidential, but you then still have the issue of distributing and verifying the public keys you are using to encrypt the symmetric keys, which is often solved by implementing an entire PKI (public key infrastructure) system, which includes CAs (certificate authorities).

You do mention using a CA, but what you are describing does not seem to be the manner in which a CA usually operates, which would usually involve the client generating their public/private key pair then sending the public half to the CA to be signed and receiving a certificate in return. These certificates can be verified by other clients due to them including the root CA certificate in their store of trusted root certificates. You've described in the comments why you're doing it differently but I'm still not sure I really follow your reasoning...

It also surprises me that the overhead of a simple symmetric encryption is too high for you. Have you actually tested the performance of this and deemed the performance hit to be unacceptable? This smells a little like premature optimisation to me, as symmetric encryption is not particularly computationally expensive (unlike asymmetric, which is why asymmetric is usually only used to negotiate a shared symmetric key which is used for any subsequent data encryption). If the overhead of a single symmetric key wrapping is too intensive then I would be surprised if you have the computational power to use encryption at all, and possibly you should rethink your approach to what it is you are attempting to do.

Comment: your right. my question needs more comments.

Comment: privacy is important in this network. so key pairs are exchanging periodically.it means CA should send a set of key pairs for each client. therefore message length is too long. if there is a way for client to share a secret number with CA, is it possible for both sides (CA and client) to use this secret num and create key pairs? if possible, communication overhead will be low.